# Synology VPN Server behind router + tethered mobile hotspot

Tags: vpn, synology

I would like to connect to my Synology VPN Server from an external location. I was able to successfully setup the Synology VPN Server and connect it through the local LAN. However, I'm unable to connect to it from an external IP.

Setup:

- Synology NAS DS216j with L2TP/IPSec VPN Server
- Router: CradelPoint
- MBR1200B Modem: ZTE MF975S Mobile HotSpot on Sprint.

I have setup port forwarding on the modem this way:

[image]

On the router it is setup the following way:

[image]

VPN passthrough is also enabled on the modem.

Any ideas? Pinging the modem doesn't gets a timeout.